# short tone in app without crashing it

Tags: java, android, beep

Yes, I did search for the answer before I posted this. :)

Made board game, each piece gets roll of die and then moves step by step on squares. Wanted to follow each step with short beep. Added method "beep();" and placed it in handler that moves position of piece on screen.

When I add beep(); game works couple of moves and then simply stops, without any report or error message. View closes on screen and dialog just says "Unfortunately, BoardLS has stopped [Ok]", and nothing else happens.

When I remove beep(); game works ok.

Please, if anyone knows how beep crashes the game, and how to avoid it, tell me as simple as you can. Thanks.

Here's how I made the beep:

```
private void beep() {
    ToneGenerator beepSound = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 60);
    beepSound.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP, 75);
} // Short sound
```

and I call it like this:

```
private final Handler playMove = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message playMsg) {
        beep();
        player.setX(pcX[playPos]);
        player.setY(pcY[playPos]);
    }
}; // Put Player piece to new coordinates
```

playPos is square number where the piece is or will be,

pcX and pcY are arrays with on-screen coordinates of squares.

handler is in MainActivity,

and called from AsyncTask with playMove.sendEmptyMessage(0);

AsyncTask works directly with global variables, making no problems here.

Comment: There should be stack trace in the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just release created `ToneGenerator`  objects using `release()` method.

```
private void beep() {
        ToneGenerator beepSound = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 60);
        beepSound.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP, 75);
        beepSound.release();
    }
```

Comment: Glad to help :)